# Similar words that change from "-ter" to "tre"

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography

I just found out that *luster* in British English was actually *lustre*. This was something that I did not know before.
Are there any other words that behave like this? Why? (According to what?)

Answer (score 8):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-re.2C_-er):

> In British usage, some words of French, Latin, or Greek origin end with a consonant followed by -re, with the -re unstressed and pronounced /ər/. 
>   Most of these words have the ending -er in the United States.
>   The difference is most common for words ending -bre or -tre: British spellings centre, *goitre, kilometre, litre, lustre, mitre, nitre, reconnoitre, saltpetre, spectre, theatre, titre, calibre, fibre, sabre,* and *sombre* all have -er in American spelling.
>
> ... Many words spelled with -re in Modern French are spelled with -er in both British and American usage; among these are *chapter, December, diameter, perimeter, disaster, enter, filter, letter, member, minister, monster, October, November, number, oyster, parameter, powder, proper, September, sober,* and *tender*.
>
> The ending -cre, as in *acre, lucre, massacre, mediocre*, is preserved in American English, to indicate the c is pronounced /k/ rather than /s/.
>
> After other consonants, there are not many -re endings ...: *louvre* and *manoeuvre* after -v; *meagre* (but not eager) and *ogre* after -g; and *euchre, ochre,* and *sepulchre* after -ch. In the United States, *ogre* and *euchre* are standard; *manoeuvre* and *sepulchre* are usually spelled as *maneuver* and *sepulcher*; ...
>
> The e preceding the r is retained in American-derived forms of nouns and verbs, for example, *fibers, reconnoitered, centering,* ... *fibres, reconnoitred* and *centring* respectively in British usage. ...
>
> Exceptions. ... include Germanic words like *anger, mother, timber, water* and Romance words like *danger, quarter, river*.
>
> ...
>
> More recent French loanwords retain an -re spelling in American English. ... double-entendre, genre, or oeuvre. ... cadre, macabre, maître d', Notre Dame, piastre, and timbre.

Comment: @mplungjan: Link rot happens.

Comment: Full entry added for the lazy and to avoid link rot, which I do not for one second believe is an issue for Wikipedia entries, quite the opposite

Comment: @mplungjan: Wikipedia articles can greatly change with time (or even get deleted).

Comment: In my experience with WP, stuff like this will not disappear. Changes are normally more than welcome. We are not talking political borders or pop stars ;)

Comment: You really should summarize this article and use excerpts from it, rather than copying the entire thing word-for-word.

Comment: see, mp, no good deed goes unpunished!

Comment: I have a life too. I feel like deleting the whole thing and posting the link as a comment. I even deleted all the foot notes and italicised the words. I do not see how I can summarize this better than just reading the damn entry. Thanks for adding the quotes though

Comment: Acceptable now @kosmo ?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the "more recent" French loan words listed in the article are not pronounced with the "er" sound at the end, even in English.

Answer (score 7):

Imposing '-er' over '-re' on words from old French is one of the orthographic simplifications by Webster when he wrote his dictionary of American English. These alternate spellings are particular to the USA, and are otherwise not preferred.

Comment: See _chapter_, _December_, _diameter_, etc.

Comment: +1 for the facts, which are relevant and not mentioned in other answers.  But the tone seems a bit unnecessarily disparaging!  If an American told me that I was “quite incorrect” for writing ‘theatre’ while I’m here, I’d find that pretty rude.  But they don’t, usually: they accept us writing ‘theatre’, ‘colour’, etc, and most Brits, Aussies etc. accept Americans writing ‘theater’, ‘color’…

Comment: @PLL: 's why it got a -1 from me.  This is an international site, not a "British English Only" site.  So, "alternate spellings" is wrong in this context.

Comment: Rereading, I think I came off unintentionally terse in my explanation.  Entirely my fault.  To rephrase, the '-er' is an American variation, and therefore, unless one is writing in American English, '-re' should be preferred.

Comment: @smithco: you can always edit your answer to make it less terse. This will also give downvoters an opportunity to change their mind (otherwise, the downvotes are locked-in).

Comment: @RegDwight Thanks for the tip, I've edited my original post accordingly.

Comment: So far as I'm aware, Webster's orthographic overhaul was one of those once-in-a-lifetime opportunities to regularise some of the more extreme examples of divergence between spelling and pronunciation. That's once in the lifetime of a language, not of a person. It's hard to see anything like that happening again. So even though I've always had a bit of a down on the man because of his dodgy etymologies, I applaud his invaluable contribution to orthography. And I certainly don't mourn the ongoing decline of many antiquated British spellings.

Answer (score 3):

In English, final unstressed -*re* after a consonant is pronounced /ər/.
Most of the words that are written with final -*re* in British English are written with final -*er* in American English to reflect the pronunciation.
The list of such words, apart from *lustre/luster*, includes:

- calibre/caliber
- centre/center
- fibre/fiber
- goitre/goiter
- kilometre/kilometer
- litre/liter
- mitre/miter
- nitre/niter
- reconnoitre/reconnoiter
- sabre/saber
- saltpetre/saltpeter
- spectre/specter
- theatre/theater
- titre/titer

There are words that are written with the final *-er* in both American and British English, even when the original words from which the English words are derived end in *re*, or contained a consonant cluster like *tr*:

- diameter (from Old French *diametre*)
- disaster (from Italian *disastro*)
- filter (from Old French *filtre*)
- monster (from Old French *monstre*)
- number (from Old French *numbre*)
- oyster (from Old French *oistre*)
- perimeter (from Greek *perimetros*)

Reference: [Wapedia](http://wapedia.mobi/en/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences?t=4).

Comment: "Wapedia" is just a Wikipedia mirror, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

There are many words like these: *centre*, *centimetre*, *fibre*, *calibre*, *litre*, just to name a few.  (Other answers have given good longer lists.)  I’m sure there are some exceptions escaping me, but all or almost all of these have the same history:

Generally, the *-re* forms are older: these words came into English from French, where they were (and mostly, still are) spelled similarly (*centre*, *centimétre*), and where the pronunciation reflects the *-re* ending.

After entering English, the pronunciations became anglicised and no longer matched the spellings — so for proponents of spelling reform, these words were an obvious target.  Most influentially, Noah Webster used the *-er* forms in his dictionary and his [‘Blue-backed Speller’](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noah_Webster#Blue_Backed_Speller); and (like many of his reforms), they caught on across the US, and are now the standard spellings there.

As far as I know, most other English-speaking countries use the *-re* forms; but as the influence of American English increases for ESL students, this may well now be changing.

Answer (score 0):

They don't "behave" like this, they just *are* different in British (or English) English and American English.  And it is, as far as I'm aware, purely historical.

Yes, there are other words with the same "-er"/"-re" difference.  "Theater"/"theatre" comes readily to mind.

Answer (score -1):

American English got rid of many homophones from British English,  using one spelling for both meanings.   Examples such as kerb/curb,  metre/meter,  practise/practice,  license/licence,  etc.
All these are used in British English but with different meanings for the different spellings.

Comment: "kerb" is actually a more recent spelling than "curb." Apparently, it comes from French "courber."