# "Center" or "centre" in sports vocabulary?

Tags: meaning, differences, orthography, sports

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Similar words that change from “-ter” to “tre”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12471/similar-words-that-change-from-ter-to-tre)

I am researching some stuff about football (soccer), and I came across the words *center* and *centre*, both of them seem to mean the same thing (i.e., middle area) but I don't know why they are different. I found a couple of sites referring to the *centre-back* (one of the defenders), and in the same sites they write *center forward* (one of the attackers).

If *center/centre* in the two positions mean the same thing (and they do), does anyone have any idea why they are spelled differently?

Comment: Related: [Similar words that change from “-ter” to “tre”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12471/similar-words-that-change-from-ter-to-tre)

Answer (score 5):

They mean the same thing.  British English uses *centre* while American English uses *center*.  Since you are looking at "football" (and not "soccer"), I would expect you to see *centre* used far more often.

Comment: To add weight to this answer, other sports in America use _centers_ not _centres_ with the most obvious being basketball.

Comment: The thing is i found Centre and Center in a couple of UK sites talking about football, thats when the doubt came up.

Comment: Could easily be a typo (since a spell checker vary well may not have picked it up).  Would you like to provide a link?

Comment: Apparently a spell checker doesn't mind "vary well" either...